# How do i make a dynamically allocated memory as a globally accessible?

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

How do i make a dynamically allocated memory as a global memory location?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
char* call(int);
char *y;

int main() {
    char *a;
    int x;
    x=45;
    a=call(x); \\ I guess it must be pointing to the Memory pointed by y
    printf(a); \\prints hello world
    x=46;
    strcpy(a,"good");
    a=call(x);
    printf(a);
}

char* call(int x) {
    y=(char *)malloc(40);
    if(x==45) {
        strcpy(y,"hello world");
        return(y);
    } else {
        return(y);
    }
}
```

I have some questions:

1. Does the memory alloacted by the `malloc()` stay until the end of program or until the end of the function where it is defined?
2. How do I make `a` and `y` point to the same address allocated by the malloc function when they are in different functions?
3. How do I make the dynamically allocated memory globally accessible?

Comment: PLEASE fix your indentation. Seriously. How does it even end up that way?

Comment: ok sorry let me make some more edits.Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Till the end of the program, or till you call `free` on that pointer
2. `a = y;` will make `a` and `y` point to the same memory location. In your case, `a = call(x);` does that too. `a` points to the memory you allocated in `call` which is still valid in `main`.
3. You've just done that.

Remember to `free(a);` in your `main`.

Answer (score 3):

1. Memory allocated by malloc is available until you explicitly free it, otherwise until the end of the program.
2. You can use global pointer or pass the pointer along the way.
3. Same as #2